# SPRING BOOT/ Failed to collect dependencies at org.springframework.boot:spring- boot-starter:jar:1.0.0.RC5

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-boot, maven

I'm new in Spring Boot and I've tried to run the simple program in Spring CLI, but it shows me an error, how can i fix it?

```
startup failed:
General error during conversion: 
org.eclipse.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: Failed to collect dependencies at org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.0.0.RC5
```

1 error

Comment: Post your code.... https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What do you mean by Spring CLI? And Version 1.0.0.RC5 is very old. Go to https://start.spring.io to create a new project

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error. Then I figured out that I was using old version of Spring Boot CLI.
version with error- spring-1.3.0.RELEASE
, working version- spring-2.6.1